# why doesn't the compiler in c++ increase the value of the last number in the loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

to be specific , in that program :

```
#include "stdafx.h"     
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;    
int main()         
{    
    int sum = 0;        
    for (int i = -100; i <=100; i++)      
    {     
        sum += i;         
        }
    cout << sum << endl;     

    return 0;
}
```

sum's value is 0 while in the condition that if i <=100 the compiler should add one to to the integer i but it didn't when the value became 100 although the condition is <= not only <
sorry for my bad English

Comment: What output did you get? What did you expect? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: please clearly explain your question.This program's output is o. what is the wrong with it?

Comment: It did add 1 when `i` became 100, so `i` is then 101. `101 <= 100` is false and thus the loop is exited before adding `101`.

Comment: What you are doing is calculating `-100-99-...-1+0+1+...+99+100`, which is `0`.
Are you sure you understand, what `sum+=i` does? You said _add one to to the integer_, but it adds `i`.

Comment: i understand what it does i am not speaking about that 
isn't i++ = i+1 ? 
so when the value becomes 100 it should become 101 
that's what i meant

Comment: because you are returning zero

Comment: thank you nwp i understood now

Comment: The increment `i++` is performed **after** the body already executed. Inside the body `i` is never >100. see [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm). It has nothing to do with returning zero.

Answer (score 0):

you did this: `-100 -99 -98 -97 ... + 97 +98 +99 +100 = 0`

Comment: because when ```i==101 ```condition``` i<=100``` is ```false``` (```101<=100```) and ```101``` is not added to sum. If you want ```-100.............+100+101``` you must change your for to ```for (int i = -100; i <=101; i++)```

Answer (score 0):

It does, but you have to understand that the loop condition (middle part, `i<=100`) is checked *after* the loop iteration statement (last part, i++) is executed. This is *not* the natural reading order.